# Converting height and inches (with decimal) to inches

Tags: sql, string, type-conversion

I have a character based height field with some irregular entries.  The most typical case is straightforward such as 6'3", or 5'11' (easy to convert).  Unfortunately, we also have some entries with a decimal in the inches value such as 5'2.5" or 5'3.25".

My goal is to convert to an integer-based total inches, taking out the decimal, and rounding to the nearest inch.

Any helps?

Comment: it is a good practice to tag the dbms being used

Comment: How are you converting the "straight-forward" cases and why are the others different?  Seems like multiplying feet by 12 and adding to the inches would work for either case.

Comment: @DStanley, simply adding the inches does not take into account that he wants it rounded to the nearest inch.

Comment: Which should be a _very_ simple change - my point is how is the OP doing it now that works for integer but not decimal inches?

Comment: It's a very good idea to store the values as numbers instead of as strings. But why do you want the inches to be rounded? Why not store all the information you have? You can always round when selecting the data. Once you store the values rounded, you could no longer select all records with a height of 5'3" or less, because you would not know anymore whether an entry with 5'3" actually means 5'2.5" or 5'3.25".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Get your feet (the number before the ') and multiply by 12, then get your inches (number between ' and ") ad round to the nearest whole number, add these numbers together and that's your height in inches :)

This query might help:

```
    SELECT
        CAST(SUBSTRING(your_column, 0, CHARINDEX ('''',your_column)) as INT)
        * 12
        + ROUND(CAST(SUBSTRING(your_column,
        CHARINDEX('''', your_column) + 1,
        LEN(your_column) - CHARINDEX('''',your_column) - 1) as DECIMAL),0)        
    as Height
```

Comment: I would have voted for this had the code been formatted as code.

Comment: How's that :) I'm new here and forgot about the code formatting, hope this is better